# Using Boto3 to send S3 Put Requests to SNS

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to get S3 put requests sent to an SNS topic. My code looks like this:

```
s3.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
    Bucket=event_name,
    NotificationConfiguration={
        'TopicConfigurations': [
            {
                'TopicArn': sns_arn,
                'Events': [
                    's3:ObjectCreated:*',
                    ],
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an exception.

```
 File "./infra_setup.py", line 73, in setup_s3_event_listener
    's3:ObjectCreated:*',
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when 
calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Access Denied
```

I haven't been able to find an example of this online using Boto3 - I am avoiding the console as I need to make this reproducible.

How can I provide the bucket/ sns topics with the necessary permissions?

The EC2 that executes this script has full SNS and S3 access, for what it's worth.

UPDATE:

Yes, it was very silly. My bucket creation was failing earlier with BucketAlreadyExists - I had assumed it existed within my account, but that's not the case. Changing the name to something unique solved that error, yielding this one instead:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

Once again, I can't find good information on solving this *in boto3*.

Comment: If you have full access, you shouldn't get `AccessDenied`.  You need to verify that the instance role has `s3:PutBucketNotification` *and* that neither the bucket policy nor the role policy have any `deny` rules that could match -- `deny` always overrides `allow`.

Comment: The instance has this:

        {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: It might also be helpful to review your bucket logs and CloudTrail logs to see what you find, there.

Comment: Yes, it was very silly. My bucket creation was failing earlier with BucketAlreadyExists - I had assumed it existed within my account, but that's not the case. Changing the name to something unique solved that error, yielding this one instead:

    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable to validate the following destination configurations

Once again, I can't find good information on solving this *in boto3*.

Comment: Manually (via console) setting the SNS topic to allow publishing from 'Everyone' works, but that seems like overkill and I want to script this.

Comment: Well, you're making progress in the right direction.  I get that you want to do it programmatically, but if you create your configuration in the console, first, it may help you figure out what you are overlooking, because the console may give you hints or tell you about something it's also going to do (like add a permission to the SNS topic policy).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to configure S3 to push put events to SNS using boto3. Note that it fully overwrites the SNS topic policy.

```
import json
import boto3

# assumes an sns topic, bucket, and queue are all created

session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=<ACCESS_ID>,
    aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET_KEY>,
)
bucket_name = <BUCKET_NAME>
topic_name = <TOPIC_NAME>

sns_resource = self.session.resource('sns')
sns_topic = sns_resource.create_topic(Name=topic_name)  # get or create

# set up SNS policy
# https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/
sns.html#SNS.Client.set_topic_attributes

sns_topic_policy = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": sns_topic.arn,
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {"AWS:SourceArn": f"arn:aws:s3:*:*:{bucket_name}"},
            },
        },
    ],
}
sns_client = session.client('sns')
sns_client.set_topic_attributes(
    TopicArn=sns_topic.arn,
    AttributeName='Policy',
    AttributeValue=json.dumps(sns_topic_policy),
)

# set up notification config
# https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketNotification.put

s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
bucket_notification = s3_resource.BucketNotification(bucket_name)
s3_notification_config = {
    'TopicConfigurations': [
        {
            'TopicArn': sns_topic.arn,
            'Events': [
                's3:ObjectCreated:*',
            ],
        },
    ],
}
response = bucket_notification.put(NotificationConfiguration=s3_notification_config)
```